# ubuntu 20.04 : any external storage device detect 4GB only

Tags: hard-drive, mass-storage

```
using Ubuntu 20.04
And any external device detected max 4GB and not able to do disk copy (dd).

[1203660.585436] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 30240768 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
[1203660.585756] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[1203660.585763] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[1203660.586087] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[1203660.748322]  sda: sda1
[1203660.750448] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk

$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
GPT PMBR size mismatch (10805404 != 7661567) will be corrected by write.
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 3.67 GiB, 3922722816 bytes, 7661568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

$ sudo dd if=test_image.bin of=/dev/sda status=progress  bs=4MB
3428000000 bytes (3.4 GB, 3.2 GiB) copied, 4 s, 857 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device
981+0 records in
980+0 records out
3922722816 bytes (3.9 GB, 3.7 GiB) copied, 4.5766 s, 857 MB/s
==
NOTE: usb-creator-gtk => Shows the proper size.

Why latest Ubuntu in my Dell laptop does not show exact size that dd command failed?
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the external storage devices with problems. What size are they? What is stored in them? What happened before your problems started? Have you rebooted (to clear possible confusion)? Please edit your original question to add answers to these questions (and reboot if you have not done it already).

Comment: Also, [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) to another question at AskUbuntu may help you analyze the problems with the drives, and let us hope, solve them.

Comment: FWIW I have on a few occasions noticed that a USB drive could not be properly read, or its contents were not readable, until I had rebooted. So please try that first.

Comment: <pre>
here kingston usb stick 16GB
[1203660.585436] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 30240768 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
Which is detected  and able to image size of 8GB in another system with ubuntu.18.04
here issue i observed with ubuntu 20.04 Dell laptop that not able to copy image > 4GB.; no usb read/write error observed.
</pre>

Comment: As mentioned  usb-creator-gtk => Shows the correct size.